# Images in cardview not supporting multiple screen sizes in android studio chipmunks

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, cardview, chipmunk

I tried to make app supporting multiple screen size it didn't work..the size of the image looks very large in tablet.

So I have created these layouts small,large,X-Large,sw-600dp and sw-700dp..(activity-main).
While testing in different mobiles top of the images are slight cut and in tablets the images are large (middle of the image can be seen).

And also I have created res/drawables(mdpi,ldpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi)
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap-content"

Where am I going wrong?[I attached cardview and image coding part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUhgs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

> try using relativelayout will adjust to the width of the mobile screen you are using